# RabbitMQ and delay message

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq

I'm trying out `RabbitMQ` and are following this tutorial: https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2015-05-19-part2-2-rabbitmq-for-beginners_example-and-sample-code-node-js.html

This has the example when receiving a message:

```
function processMsg(msg) {
  work(msg, function(ok) {
    try {
      if (ok)
        ch.ack(msg);
      else
        ch.reject(msg, true);
    } catch (e) {
      closeOnErr(e);
    }
  });
}
```

Is it possible instead of `reject` the message to put it back in the queue with a `delay` - for getting later, perhaps 30 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for RabbitMQ named [RabbitMQ Delayed Message Plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2015/04/16/scheduling-messages-with-rabbitmq/). The link contains an example, as it is a blog post from RabbitMQ.

It basically allows you to publish a message with a header `headers.put("x-delay", 5000);` which is what you want.

But I think that you need use a new, specialized exchange for this. Luckily `args.put("x-delayed-type", "direct");` can be of any of the currently existing exchange types (also custom ones).

I wouldn't recommend to do this server-side (node-js) because unless you store the message in a database, it will be lost if the server is restarted. Also, you might end up in a situation where you have lots of timeouts waiting.

Apparently the plugin persists the messages so that if the RabbitMQ server is restarted, the message will still be sent.

Comment: Would that work on messages pulled from the queue - I need to add the delay on an already created message from the queue.